# How can you specify an order for quote marks in LaTeX?

Tags: formatting, syntax, quoting

I have a segment where the original text uses two different quote marks next to each other like `"''"` to show speech within a quote. I need to recreate this in LaTeX.

```
\subsection{35}
This from Plato: `` `To the man who has true grandeur of mind, and who contemplates all time and all being, can human life appear a great matter?' `Impossible,' says the other. `Can then such a one count death a thing of dread?' `No, indeed.' ''
```

That is approximately what I'm trying to do. The problem is the spaces between the quotes at the start and end are not supposed to be there but without them the quote marks are in the wrong order. It is supposed to be `"''"` but without spaces it is `"'"'`. How can I make LaTeX understand which pair of characters forms a double quote and which one is the single when there are 3 quote characters in a row?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  In the TeXbook, Knuth recommends setting a thin space (which won't break at the end of a line) to make the distinction clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\,` between the single and double quotes.

```
\subsection{35}
This from Plato: ``\,`To the man who has true grandeur of mind, and who contemplates all time and all being, can human life appear a great matter?' `Impossible,' says the other. `Can then such a one count death a thing of dread?' `No, indeed.'\,'’
```

Comment: This does put a small space between the quote marks (which may be typographically desired or not, I suppose.)

Comment: It is the desired practice. Without the space “‘ and ’” are indistinguishable in many fonts.

Comment: That's just what I needed. What is the `\,` thing called and what exactly does it do? I can't find good search results for it.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor This question covers most of them I think. The `\,` is called a thin space. [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/74353)

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable way to deal with complex quoting is to use proper markup and the `csquotes` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\begin{document}

This from Plato: \enquote{\enquote{To the man who has true grandeur
of mind, and who contemplates all time and all being, can human life
appear a great matter?} \enquote{Impossible,} says the other.
\enquote{Can then such a one count death a thing of
dread?} \enquote{No, indeed.}}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Why the downvote here? Is there something wrong with this answer?

Comment: I wonder if the downvoter is using luatex. Anyway, this is not enough reason to downvote it, I think.

Comment: @JavierBezos But `csquotes` also works with LuaLaTeX, doesn't it? At least I have not experienced any issues with `csquotes` and LuaLaTeX and have not heard about any issues either.

Comment: Surely that can't be a reason to downvote, but the code does not quite produce the output in the picture. The picture has a space before the `\enquote{No, indeed.}`, while the code does not.

Comment: @moewe The answer has been edited to remove a solution based on inserting `{}`, which doesn't work in `luatex` (but does in `pdftex` and `xetex`).

Comment: @JavierBezos The downvote preceded that edit, though. But I hadn't realized that the `{}` solution didn't work in LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @JavierBezos Ahhh, that explains it. I only saw the `csquotes` solution, which works perfectly fine in LuaLaTeX as far as I can tell. (Even though I have heard people argue that `csquotes` is not useful for Unicode engines, because you can just type your preferred quotation mark character in directly. A point I do not agree with.)